# how to create c++ template function with vector?

Tags: c++

I have been trying to create a template of the following function.

```
static void search(vector <Cleassname> c, string str);
```

i tried something like this in my .h file

```
template <typename T, typename U> static void search(vector <T*> c, U str);
```

and in my .cpp file i tried

```
template <typename T, typename U> void CLASS::search(vector <T*> c, U str){}
```

i declared vector  vector_var and passing its address to the function using &
wheneveer i call upon the fonction in main(), it says there no reference to such function.

```
CLASS::search(&vector_var, mystring);
```

Comment: I don't know what `vector` is in your last line, but I doubt that `&vector` is a `vector<T*>`. More likely a `vector<T>*`. Also, why would you want to template `str`?

Comment: i have declared vector <class> vector_var in my main. that's what i'm passing to my function like. CLASS:search(&vector_var, mystring). just passing the address to the pointer parameter.

Comment: But, again, your function takes a vector of pointers to `T`, not a pointer to a vector of `T`s.